# How can I create a Wordpress website that does this kind of image processing

Tags: wordpress, image-processing

I am just a beginner in web development and want someone to guide me on this. I know how to build a basic Wordpress website. What I want is a functionality on my WordPress site which will take some text and an image provided by the user and process it to make a final image as shown below :
[image]

I have no idea how to do it. If anyone could guide me how to achieve this, I mean what kind of tools I need or a reference guide will also help.

Thank you so much for reading :)

Comment: This question is outside the scope of Stack Overflow, see: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) You are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting, and questions should include a summary of what you have tried so far and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and come back if you have a specific coding question to ask.

Comment: What most people on StackOverflow do not understand is sometimes users asking a question just want a direction or a reference. They are not expecting a full descriptive answer. Instead of adding a comment like the above, you could just have answered it in one line, just like rob-art did.

Comment: It's not that they don't understand... its that those types of questions are outside the scope of this site, as outlined in the Help section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to the PHP librairie named GD.
You can create an image, add some text, some colors and moreover add an existing image (your user image).
There is a lot of tutorials for this librairie on the internet.

Comment: Thank you rob-art for the reference. This is exactly what I needed for a head start :)